# Custom jquery plugin doesnt print name of the element if it is clicked

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I m trying to create a simple jquery plugin. here is the link for what I have got so far

http://jsfiddle.net/T4G96/

```
(function ($) {

    $.bsDatepicker= function(element) {

        var $element=$(element);

        $element.attr("readonly","readonly");


        $element.on("mousedown",function(){
            renderCalendar();

        });




    renderCalendar = function(){
        alert($element.attr("name"));

    }

  }

     $.fn.bsDatepicker = function(options) {

        return this.each(function() {
            $abc=$(this);
            // if element has a date picker already attached
            if (undefined != $(this).data('bsDatepicker')) {

                // get reference to the previously attached date picker
                var plugin = $(this).data('bsDatepicker');

                // remove the attached icon (if it exists)...


            }

            // create a new instance of the plugin
            var plugin = new $.bsDatepicker(this, options);

            // save a reference to the newly created object
            $(this).data('bsDatepicker', plugin);

        });

    }

})(jQuery)

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cal").bsDatepicker();
    $("#cal2").bsDatepicker();
});
```

The problem I m facing is i m implementing this plugin to two textboxes with different name and id. I have outputted the element name in console on mousedown event. The problem here is it always outputs the second textbox name. It should print the name of element its being clicked. What Am i doing wrong here? Any help will highly be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like the second instance of your plugin is overriding something from the first instance? For example, if you remove the second instance or add a third one, the alert will show the name of the first and third instance textbox respectively.

Comment: Well the last instance overrides the rest one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass a reference of the element that triggered the event to your `renderCalendar()` function instead of trying to read it from the variable

```
$element.on("mousedown",function(){
    renderCalendar(this);       
});

renderCalendar = function(element){
    alert($(element).attr("name")); 
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T4G96/1/)**